# msbuild conversion tool to VS2010

Tags: visual-studio, qt, msbuild

I got vcproj file from QMake (qmake -tp vc win32.pro), and when I run it with msbuild (msbuild for VS 2010), I get the following error.

```
MSBUILD : error MSB4192: The project file ".\win32.vcproj" is in the ".vcproj" or ".dsp" file format
, which MSBuild cannot build directly. Please convert the project by opening it in the Visual Studio
 IDE or running the conversion tool, or, for ".vcproj", use MSBuild to build the solution file conta
ining the project instead.
```

I'd like to run the conversion tool for getting VS2010 project file. What's the tool for it?

### ADDED

Based on heavyd's answer, I got it work.

```
qmake -project
qmake -tp vc win32.pro
devenv /Upgrade win32.vcproj
msbuild win32.vcxproj
```

One can use nmake, which is simpler.

```
qmake -spec win32-msvc2008
nmake
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The conversion tools is built into the Visual Studio IDE.  You can run it by opening a Visual Studio 2010 Command Prompt (Start->Microsoft Visual Studio 2010->Visual Studio Tools) and typing:

```
devenv /Upgrade example.vcproj
```

Where `example.vcproj` is your VS 2005/2008 Visual C++ project file.  This should upgrade you project to VS 2010 so it can be built directly with MSBuild.